# Deadlock using Convert.ChangeType within Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading

I just had to debug a code with a deadlock, but I can't really find the reason why. In detail the deadlock happens when calling `Convert.ChangeType` within a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

I try to find any Information about the thread-safety of this method, but I wasn't able to find some. So I had a look at the .NET source code and tried to do what they do, so I don't need to call `Convert.ChangeType`. And finally the code run without the deadlock.

In my example code I convert an enumeration type to its underlaying ulong type:

```
public class TestClass<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    private static readonly Type uLongType = typeof(ulong);
    public static readonly TestClass<T> Instance = new TestClass<T>();

    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _NumericValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, T> _Values = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    public TestClass()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration type required");
        Type t = typeof(T);
        foreach (T value in Enum.GetValues(t)) _Values[Enum.GetName(t, value)] = value;
        // Deadlock at Convert.ChangeType
        Parallel.ForEach(ValueNames, new Action<string>((key) =>
        {
            object value = Convert.ChangeType(_Values[key], uLongType);
            lock (_NumericValues) _NumericValues[key] = value;
            // In real life here comes a lot more code...
        }));
        // Works!
        Parallel.ForEach(ValueNames, new Action<string>((key) =>
        {
            object value = ((IConvertible)_Values[key]).ToUInt64(null);
            lock (_NumericValues) _NumericValues[key] = value;
        }));
    }

    public string[] ValueNames => new List<string>(_Values.Keys).ToArray();
}

public enum TestEnum : ulong
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}
```

To reproduce f.e.:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TestClass<TestEnum>.Instance.ValueNames.Length);
```

But I don't really understand, why `Convert.ChangeType` is causing a deadlock - does anyone have any idea?

**Edit**: It works with `Convert.ChangeType`, if I initialize `Instance` within a static constructor - but why the heck?

```
    public static readonly TestClass<T> Instance = null;

    static TestClass()
    {
        Instance = new TestClass<T>();
    }
```

Comment: just for completeness it would be nice to see how _Values and _NumericValues are declared and what is ValueNames, what values does it contain. We should be able to create a version of your code locally and debug ourselves then

Comment: Note that `Convert.ToUInt64(_Values[key])` is going to be a lot cheaper than `Convert.ChangeType(_Values[key], typeof(ulong))`. However, `Convert.ChangeType` does just do a bunch of checks to see which `IConvertable.ToXXX` method to call, and then it calls it, so I don't see why its behaviour should be any different to calling `IConvertable.ToUInt64` directly, nor why it should deadlock.

Comment: I think we do need to see all of the code required to reproduce this, *and* see the evidence which makes you think it's deadlocked (and not just being slow, for example).

Comment: Ok, I'll edit and add a full working example code for that issue.

Comment: @Dave My edit is done. With the code above you should be able to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: Just to make sure - you understand that `Parallel` brings performance degradation here and would work much faster without TPL, right? The question is very interesting in terms of curiosity, but has no practical usage.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Sure `Parallel` does produce a lot of overhead in this example, because there are only a very few values in the example enumeration. And yes, I'm asking that question because of the problem is curios to me, too ;) I'm not able to understand why a static constructor-time initialization of `Instance` makes the difference when using `Convert.ChangeType` without any explain...

Comment: Just to say, `Convert.ToUInt64` causes deadlock as well.

Comment: Well all Convert.ToUInt64 does it [call IConvertable.ToUInt64](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1343) so whatever is causing your deadlock, if it is a deadlock, I don't think it's where you think it is.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, now I think so, too. The reason must be within the difference initializing the static field `Instance` in a static constructor or in the field definition. I thought it doesn't make a difference - but in this special case, when working with `Parellel.ForEach` and calling `Convert.ChangeType` it does.

Comment: Ah, look at the BeforeFieldInit flag. I'll look at this in more detail when I'm back at a computer.

Comment: @canton7 http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx <- You mean this one? I think that's the answer...

Comment: That's the one. That'll be the difference between your "fine" and "deadlocked" scenarios, but I haven't yet worked out why the deadlock occurs, or why BeforeFieldInit changes that. A debugger should help, I'll break one out tomorrow.

Comment: You're locking _NumericValues.  My understanding is that you should lock a separate _static_ lock object if you're using lock this way.

Comment: You might also solve your problem by using ConcurrentBag<T> instead of a dictionary.  Dictionary is not thread safe, while objects in the Concurrent namespace are.

Comment: @BrianWhite Thanks for your tipps! After the class was instanced, all other code will access the variables read-only, so a concurrent bag is not required here. In other codes I use a static object for thread-locking within static methods. In instanced classes I use an object for thread locking of the instance, unless I want to lock something for all instances. Locking `NumericValues` directly should be safe, since it happens in the construction code, so no other thread will be able to access the object (properties), if I don't cause it.

Comment: Well, concurrent bag might still be useful since you were having problems with parallel access while loading it with data.  If you're going multi threaded you should by default use the objects in System.Concurrent.  They have code which carefully takes only the weight of a lock which is necessary, like they might use ReaderWriterLockSlim and lots of other performance improving code.

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary would make more sense, sorry I said ConcurrentBag earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is purely that you are performing a blocking operating inside a type initializer. The CLR has to run type initializers inside a lock, as it has to prevent them from ever being run twice, and it uses the same lock for all types. If you do threading inside your type initializer, *and* you block, then you risk deadlock.

I think that's exactly what's happening here:

1. The main thread grabs the type initializer lock and runs the type initializer
2. Another thread is spawned, which accesses the `Convert` class, which needs to run its type initializer. So it tries to grab the type initializer lock
3. The main thread blocks waiting for the second thread to complete, holding the type initializer lock
4. Deadlock

You didn't see this when calling `IConvertable.ToUInt64` directly, because that didn't need to call the `Convert` class's type initializer.

When your `TestClass<T>.Instance` is assigned inline, the `BeforeFieldInit` flag gets set. This means the CLR uses a relaxed approach to running the type initializer, and in my testing it ran it before `Main`, before the type initializer for `Convert` had been run. When you defined an explicit static constructor, the CLR was forced to run the type initializer when `TestClass<T>.Instance` was first referenced in `Main`, presumably after `Convert` had been initialized, which happened to avoid the deadlock.

My evidence for this is knowledge of how type initializers are run, the fact that the thread blocks somewhere inside the runtime (but before it gets a chance to run the method `Convert.ChangeType`), and the fact that merely referencing the `Convert` type is enough to trigger this.

See [this MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/05/03/static-constructor-deadlocks/). I think the takeaway is that you probably shouldn't be doing threading in your type initializer, and you definitely shouldn't be blocking the thread which is running the type initializer.

I'd be happy to take at your actual (non-simplified) problem, and try a suggest ways of improving its performance without resorting to threading in the type initializer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explaination! The Information from the MSDN article and http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx helped a lot, too. Now I have to overwork some static class code to use a static constructor for initializing the static fields… In my opinion the type initialization behavior should be changed to avoid such problems. But if I know about that, I can write the code in a way that avoids problems like that.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is nothing to do with `Convert.ChangeType`, it just happens to exhibit the issue because the call references the static `uLongType` field, which causes the `TestClass<T>` type initializer to run.

The real culprit is the static `Instance` field that creates a new `TestClass<T>` instance. This creates a potential deadlock as the type initializer requires the instance constructor to complete, but the instance constructor is waiting on multiple threads which in turn wait for the type initializer to complete.

Adding a static constructor, which removes the `beforefieldinit` type attribute and changes type initialization behavior as mentioned in the comments, only semi-reliably hides the deadlock in combination with an attached debugger in my tests. It doesn't really solve the issue.

Here is a simplified example which exhibits the problem most of the time:

```
static void Main()
{
    new TestClass();
    Console.WriteLine("Not deadlocked");
}

public class TestClass
{
    static Type uLongType = typeof(ulong);
    static TestClass Instance = new TestClass();

    static TestClass() { }

    public TestClass()
    {
        var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToList();

        Parallel.ForEach(values, (value) =>
        {
            uLongType.ToString();

            //Forcing the lambda to be compiled as an instance method
            //changes the behavior but deadlocks can happen either way
            InstanceMethod();
        });
    }

    void InstanceMethod() { }
}
```

The deadlocking probability varies depending on the combination of instance and/or static usage in the lambda, attached debugger, release optimizations, static constructor, `Console.WriteLine` call in the lambda, and random `Parallel` thread scheduling, but it can always happen.

Comment: Thank you for explaining - I think the solution is simple: The `Instance` field is now a property that has a getter. This getter checks if the (new) static field `_Instance` is `null`, otherwise it creates the instance of the class that uses `Parallel` in the constructor. Since the method will be invoked after the type initialized, I only have to lock `_Instance` for the check & construction. This works pretty good for me :)

Comment: I don't think this is quite the whole story: he also said he saw a deadlock with Convert.ToUInt64, which doesn't reference a static field. I haven't tried that scenario myself though.